# Dynamically checking height of table inside for loop as rows are added

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the below snippet of code, some variables have been excluded for privacy:

```
    var curr_table = 1;
    var table = document.getElementById("open_tickets_" + curr_table + "").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    if (Number(allResults.length) > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < Number(allResults.length); i++) {
        var currentTime = allResults[i].Created;
        if (!arrayOfTimes.includes(currentTime)) {

          if(document.getElementById("open_tickets_" + curr_table + "").offsetHeight >= 1000){
            curr_table++;
            console.log(curr_table);
            $("nav-openTickets").append("<table class=\"table table-striped\" id=\"open_tickets_" + curr_table + "\"><thead class=\"thead-light\"><tr><th style=\"width:200px;\">Date</th><th>XX</th><th>XXX</th><th style=\"width:200px;\">XXX</th><th>XXX</th><th style=\"width:100px;\">XXX</th><th>XXX</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
          }
          var row = table.insertRow(0);
          var date_cell = row.insertCell(0);
          date_cell.innerHTML = dateOpened;
          var xx_cell = row.insertCell(1);
          xx_cell.innerHTML = XX;
          var xx_cell = row.insertCell(2);
          xx_cell.innerHTML = XX;
          var xx_cell = row.insertCell(3);
          xx_cell.innerHTML = XX;
          var xx_cell = row.insertCell(4);
          xx_cell.innerHTML = XX;
          var xx_cell = row.insertCell(5);
          xx_cell.innerHTML = XX;
          var xx_cell = row.insertCell(6);
          xx_cell.innerHTML = XX;
          var xx_cell = row.insertCell(7);
          xx_cell.innerHTML = XX;
          
          arrayOfTimes.push(currentTime);
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm trying to check the tables height as the rows are added inside of this for loop (variables and data are pulled from a database). The code adds rows to the table, but it doesn't execute the if statement that checks the tables height to create a new table for rows to be added to. The offsetHeight always returns 0.

I need to split the tables into different tables when they exceed a certain height - How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just count the number of rows being added, and start a new table when it exceeds some threshold?

Comment: @kmoser the rows are not the same height - some contain more data then others. It's impossible to know just off the number of rows.

Comment: FYI, if `allResults` is an array, `allResults.length` will always return a number; there is no reason to call `Number(allResults.length)`.

Comment: I just ran your code (with a few minor modifications to make a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and it seems to work: `document.getElementById("open_tickets_" + curr_table + "").offsetHeight` increases by 24 with every row added. What happens when you `console.log(document.getElementById("open_tickets_" + curr_table + "").offsetHeight)` every time through the loop (not inside the `if()`)?

Comment: It logs 0 (in my case 47 times as theres 47 rows being added) @kmoser - Perhaps it's important that all of this code is inside the success function of an ajax call. Not sure if that would change the outcome.

Comment: As a matter of fact, in my case it seems like the problem is that the rows are not added visually until the very last row is added - so it thinks the table height is 0 until at the end of the loop they all populate instantly.

Comment: Actually adding the rows to the table and updating the height would slow the browser down, so many browsers defer that until there's a pause. If I was you I'd take a conservative guess at the number of rows per page (maybe -3) and build that many rows. Run that inside a `requestAnimationFrame` callback. Once that returns, check the height. Add some more rows in another `requestAnimationFrame` callback. Check the height. If you've hit the threshold, create the new table and begin the process again. Keep doing that until 0 records. I don't have time to write that code, but hope it helps.